# How to replace comma ',' in an array to ' / ' using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I replace ',' with a '/' in an array using JavaScript. Here my array has two string values separated by a comma ',' but I want to make it in form of a single string separating the values by '/' ?

For example: array[] = `{ value1, a1/a2/a3}` to be replaced by array[] = `{value1/a1/a2/a3}`

For example: Here I want to replace the outcome which comes as `[3,101/102/103]` by `[3/101/102/103].`

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Try `array.join('/');`

Comment: please explain more the structure of your array. Is it this way [{ value1, a1/a2/a3},...]

Comment: Well, may be I didn't get your point but it seems like there are two values stored in your array. And it's array internal structure to separate them. If I didn't get you right, please let me know.

Comment: @Brian, the appropriate spelling for JavaScript is JavaScript, with a capital J and a capital S. This can be seen in the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes: Noted. Gosh I've had my pedantry pedanted.   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(target, replacement) {
  return this.split(target).join(replacement);
};
array = new Array("a1/a2/a3")

for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("/",",")
}
```

does this help?

Answer (score 13):

This will make a one-element array with your complete string:

```
var newArr = arr.join(',').replace(/,/g, '/').split();
```

Comment: The issue is solved and .join is the right option, Thanks Andy, Mohamed, Tushar.You guys are perfect about this solution

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

```
var array = ['1', '2/3/4/5'], array2 = [];

array2.push(array.join('/'));
```