# How do I change the delimiter from comma to pipe in the following JS?

Tags: javascript

The delimiter for the output of the following JS function is a comma between values. How do I change this to a pipe: '|' ?

```
function siteHier(){

    // Grab Path
    var myUrlOriginal = window.location.pathname;

    // Remove everything after first '.'
    var oPath = myUrlOriginal.substr(0, myUrlOriginal.lastIndexOf("."));
    //console.log(oPath);

    // Split data into sections
    var nPath = oPath.split('/');
    //console.log('Hier: ' + nPath);

    // Replace ',' with '|'
    var stringReplaceFrom = /,/g;
    var stringReplaceTo = '|';
    var dPath = nPath.join(',').replace(stringReplaceFrom,stringReplaceTo).split();
    //var dPath = nPath;
    console.log(dPath);

    // Final Value
    var hPath = 'homepage' + dPath;
    //console.log(hPath);

    return hPath;
}
```

Comment: It appears that the delimiter (when you call `split`) is a forward slash. Where is the comma?

Comment: The comma is added by default Elliott. What `.split()` does is separates the segments at '/'. I am talking about the output when putting everything back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace something with javascript, you can use the `.replace()` method.

The first parameter of this method can be a Regular expression of what you are looking for. The second one is the string you want to replace it with.

You just need a simple Replace so you can use this kind of example:

```
var string = 'some,string';
string.replace(/,/g , '|'); //output: some|string
```

But be carefull! It will replace each appear of the sign!

Comment: I'll try this later today; however, your solution will definitely work from first glance. Thanks Nano.

Comment: I added your solution, but it gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: I updated the OP with the latest code that is giving the Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: The replace function is not available for arrays (what your split returns). Do the replace before the split

Comment: What I ended up doing is: `var stringReplaceFrom = /,/g;var stringReplaceTo = '|';var dPath = nPath.join(',').replace(stringReplaceFrom,stringReplaceTo).split();`

Comment: I found the solution for replace() here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118846/how-to-replace-comma-in-an-arraylist-to-using-javascript

Comment: why dont you put the replace function there: `var nPath = Path.replace(stringReplaceFrom,stringReplaceTo).split('/');` ???